# GPS waypoint navigation with Jackal

Tags: navigation, gps, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a the UGV "Jackal" from Clearpath Robotics. My Task is to let the robot follow a predetermined path (given in UTM -Coordinates). The robot has already GPS, IMU and odometry implemented. The `robot_localization` package is also already installed and preconfigured.

To let the robot navigate autonomously, I would like to use the `move_base` package. Therefore the goals (`move_base/goal` or `move_base_simple/goal`) have to be "in the robots world frame, or a frame that can be transormed to the world frame" (see Answer for this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/251347/gps-waypoint-navigation-with-robot_localization-and-navsat_transform_node/)).
The `robot_localization` package should provide a transform from  **world_frame->utm**. But when I start the robot outside, I cant't see this transformation in the `tf` node. Because of that I can't send goals to the `move_base` node with `frame_id` **utm** I think.

My Questions are now:

1. Where can I check that the `navsat_transform_node` provides the **world_frame -> utm** transformation?
2. How should I configure the `move_base` node that he will accepts goals in the utm-frame? (I know this is a very open question, but I am very glad for every tip.)

Thank you for your help and support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259620/gps-waypoint-navigation-with-jackal/) by [P_Brand](https://answers.ros.org/users/30076/p_brand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manuelmelvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30611/manuelmelvin/) on 2021-09-21**:
Hello..
I am facing the same issue with my Jackal robot. Could you please help me to resolve this. I also need to send the jackal robot to follow certain GPS waypoints. I have all the Jackal packages installed. I launched the base.launch, move_base.launch and Rviz view_robot.launch. Have added the below "robot_localization" inside the base.launch and  I made "broadcast_utm_transform=true" .

magnetic_declination_radians: 0
      roll_offset: 0
      pitch_offset: 0
      yaw_offset: 0
      zero_altitude: false
      broadcast_utm_transform: true

But I am not able to see the UTM under the tree. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. First, make sure that `navsat_transform` is broadcasting the **world_frame->utm** transform (you've probably already done this). In your launch file for `navsat_transform` make sure that `broadcast_utm_transform=true`. Next, launch Rviz and check the **TF** tree, you should see something like this:
   [image: image description]

You should see `utm` in the list. Note that for reasons explained [here on the docs page](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html), the `utm` frame is actually a child of the map/world_frame.

Also as an FYI, even though the `utm` frame is there, it doesn't seem to show up when you run `rosrun tf view_frames` (at least not for me anyway). The easiest way I've found to check the existence of the `utm` frame is to check it like this in Rviz.

2. The `move_base` node should accept move goals in any frame, provided there is a valid transformation between the frame you specify and the `base_link` frame. The easiest way to do this is just to send a [PoseStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) message to the `/move_base_simple/goal` topic. You should be able to specify whatever frame you want in the header.

If you want a more complicated way of doing this that also lets you get feedback on your goal, I suggest you look at the [actionlib package](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) and these questions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/252236/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-give-a-robot-a-predefined-set-of-waypoints/#252266) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/240385/base_local_planner-simplest-navigation-no-curve-lines/#240742) for more information and some sample code.

Hopefully this helps or at least points you in the right direction. Let me know how you get on, and if any specific error messages appear when you try sending a move goal in the `utm` frame, post those as well since that might help debug the problem.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [P_Brand](https://answers.ros.org/users/30076/p_brand/) on 2017-04-20**:
Thank you for your help, I will try this out!

**Comment by [P_Brand](https://answers.ros.org/users/30076/p_brand/) on 2017-04-21**:
I tried this out and it worked! I can see now the **utm**- frame in the tf Tree. When I `rosrun tf view_frames` the utm - frame doesn't appear in the PDF like you expected. When I send a PoseStamped message to the `/move_base_simple/goal` topic (with `frame_id: "utm"` ), the robot starts to move.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2017-04-22**:
Awesome! I'm glad that fixed your problem!